# Collection database software (self-hosted)

Tags: linux, web-apps, database, ubuntu, collection-manager

I've been looking for a while for a program to better manage my various collections (DVDs, games, books). Although I've found programs that can do that they are generally local desktop programs which doesn't suit my needs.

What I'm looking for is:

- Self-hosted (I have a VPS and want to use to access my database anywhere)
- Has to run on Ubuntu
- Uses a database, any will work (though MySQL would be easiest I imagine)
- Has a web interface so I can just map a virtual host on my VPS to reach it
- Web interface should have the option to add new items / remove items / change fields or fill fields
- Customizable fields would be nice as well

Since I'm not capable of writing something like this on my own I'd love to have some program that fits the above to work with.